# Passing props from function-components to class components ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

Please help me.

How can I call the changeAutoSlide() function  on the class component Slide. How to pass this function to Parent.

Here function View is Child and class Slide is Parent component.

I want to stop the interval on component Slide with life cycle

Thanks.

```
export default class Slider extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.autoSlide();
  }

  autoSlide = (interval) => {
    return interval;
  };

  render() {
    return <View autoSlide={this.autoSlide} />;
  }
}

const View = () => {
  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(1);

  const setIndex = () => {
    if (slideIndex > 0) {
      setSlideIndex(slideIndex + 1);
    }
    if (slideIndex === 20) {
      setSlideIndex(20 - slideIndex + 1);
    }
  };
  const changeAutoSlide = () => {
    const interval = setInterval(setIndex, 2000);
    return autoSlide(interval);
  };

  changeAutoSlide();  //// I want pass this func on component Slide

  return (
    <section>
      <h2>Hello React</h2>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please refer to relevant docs and its tutorials https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage the state (slideIndex) and its functions in the parent class component:

```
export default class Slider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      slideIndex: 1
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.autoSlide();
  }

  setIndex = () => {
    if (this.state.slideIndex > 0) {
      this.setState({
        slideIndex: this.state.slideIndex + 1
      }) 
    }
    if (this.state.slideIndex === 20) {
      this.setState({
        slideIndex: 20 - this.state.slideIndex + 1
      }) 
    }
  };

  changeAutoSlide = () => {
    const interval = setInterval(setIndex, 2000);
    return this.autoSlide(interval);
  };

  autoSlide = (interval) => {
    return interval;
  };

  render() {
    return <View autoSlide={this.autoSlide} setIndex={this.setIndex} changeAutoSlide={this.changeAutoSlide} />;
  }
}
```

And from the Child component receive and use those props:

```
const View = (props) => {
  // Use the props in this component like: 
  // props.changeAutoSlide()
  // props.autoSlide 
  // props.setIndex()

  return (
    <section>
      <h2>Hello React</h2>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Please take the time to read more about how React data flows: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down

Comment: Thank you everyone very much for taking care of my problem. 
Alex Yepes your code helped me.  Slide is working. I hope you will help me again in the future. I'm from Uzbekistan.

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped you, could you please mark it as the answer to this question? Happy coding :)

Comment: @ShuxratOmonqulov ^^^^

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the silder in child from parent then you can try passing it a boolean

```
class Slider extends Component { 

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // Don't call this.setState() here!
  this.state = { autoSlide: false };

}

   render () {
      return <View autoSlide={this.state.autoSlide} />;
   }

}

const View = ({ autoSlide = false }) => {

   useEffect(() => {

     // depending on autoSlide, you can stop or start the interval here

     let intervalId
     if (autoSlide) { 
        intervalId = setInterval(setIndex, 2000);
     }

     return () => {
        // cleanup previous interval here
        intervalId && clearInterval(intervalId)
     }

   }, [autoSlide])

   return (
    
   )

}
```

I hope this guides you in some way, check out the [useEffect docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects) to get a better understanding